# Comparing two arrays in C without case sensitivity

Tags: arrays, c

I have for example two arrays

char 1 is:    77a abcd Abc abc1d @#@# v k

char2 is:     789 ABA AABB 123 ab #% abcde

The common index should be in places  0,3,4,5,9,10,12,20

The result should be 8 but I get 9 The problem is that an Aski code lower than 64 still works and it should not
Is the code

```
int intersection(char arrayNumberOne[size], char arrayNumberTwo[size])
{
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(arrayNumberOne); i++)
    {
        if ((arrayNumberOne[i] == arrayNumberTwo[i]) || (arrayNumberOne[i] == arrayNumberTwo[i] + 32) || (arrayNumberOne[i] + 32 == arrayNumberTwo[i]))
        {
            if (arrayNumberOne[i] < 64)
            {
                ?????
            }
            
            
                counter++;
            
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Use `tolower` (or `toupper`) on each element before comparing.

Comment: Is the goal to compare _strings_ or arrays of characters?

Comment: char arrays i need

Comment: What is the magic number `64`?

Comment: You are messing with letter ASCII codes. It's much better to follow @EugeneSh. 's advice and use `toupper` or `tolower`. Look at [its docs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_toupper.htm). It will use uppercase letters, or the original symbol if its not a letter. Use it in both members of the comparison.

Comment: The number 64 is special because in the Askie table everyone below is the same numbers or keyboard marks I have a bug
If I enter R and 2 it is basically the same Aski code then the program does not really realize itself and why does this happen because I added 32 at first but without 32 there will be no difference between A and a

Comment: If you are using the magic number 64 because of its position in the ascii table, you should probably write it as `'A' - 1`.  And that immediately indicates that perhaps it is a bug and you actually meant either `<= 'A' ` or `< 'A'`.  Whatever it is, it is much clearer of you don't hard code `64`

Comment: Where is assurance coming from that if we step `i` from` 0` to just below `strlen(arrayNumberOne)`, then those array indices are valid for `arrayNumberTwo`?

Comment: If you're comparing arrays of characters (as it appears) don't use `strlen()` it expects a string (with a 0 terminator). 
If you're comparing strings pass them as `const char *` not arrays and handle them being different lengths (unless you have a constraint guaranteeing equal lengths.
As it stands it looks like you're confusing 'string' and 'array of character'. They're similar but not handled the same way.

Comment: There are pitfalls in using `tolower` and `toupper`, because the input value must be in the non-negative range `0` o `UCHAR_MAX` or else the value `EOF`. The behavior is undefined otherwise. This does not line up with the type `char`, which could be signed and have a range of negative values. These functions should not be casually recommended to newbies.

Answer (score 0):

Use tolower, no need to do strlen and you need to check both string length.

cast to `(unsigned char)` this allow to avoid an undefined behavior if char is a signed type (which it often is) and if any of the arrays contain negative char values (that are different from EOF: the one negative value permitted in tolower) (thanks @Kaz to flag this)

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int intersection(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    int counter = 0;

    while (*s1 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0') {
        if (tolower((unsigned char) *s1++) == tolower((unsigned char) *s2++)) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}


int main() {
    printf("%d\n", intersection("77a abcd Abc abc1d @#@# v k",
                                "789 ABA AABB 123 ab #% abcde"));
    return 0;
}
```

Returns `8`

Answer (score 0):

Sum 32 to an ASCII character can lead to undesirable combinations, and you already found the issue.

I suggest you, break your conditionals into small pieces and there are some small changes:

First, the condition about the symbols is incomplete, then change:

`if (arrayNumberOne[i] < 64)`

to:

`if (arrayNumberOne[i] <= 64 || arrayNumberTwo[i] <= 64)`

Because both arrays could contain a symbol.

Second, organize the expressions to see the logic better, but you can join after all:

```
// considering inside a for-loop used 'continue' to skip the other verifications

// compare any character
// both lower case or upper case
if (arrayNumberOne[i] == arrayNumberTwo[i]) {
   counter++;
   continue;
}

// is a symbol, skip the verification ahead
if (arrayNumberOne[i] <= 64 || arrayNumberTwo[i] <= 64)
   continue;

// character verifications

// first is uppercase
if (arrayNumberOne[i] + 32 == arrayNumberTwo[i]) {
   counter++;
   continue;
}

// second is uppercase
if (arrayNumberOne[i] == arrayNumberTwo[i] + 32) {
   counter++;
   continue;
}
```

This will make your code work but would be better to check for 'a-z' or use tolower as they said in the comments/answers.